# What is nbot and why is it crawling my site?

Tags: bots

In Awstats the number 2 bot in my list of bots and spiders is called **nbot**. It does not show up in Distil's bot directory, so I am thinking this is not an actual known bot.

Does anybody know what it is, and if I can safely block it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a group name for bots Awstats does not recognize. If you are having an issue, I suggest digging into your raw logs and searching for the specific name of the bot causing your bandwidth issues.